# qsort() and casting operation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting, qsort

Consider an array of **pointers to structs**. The following code is taken from an example you may find [here](http://c-faq.com/lib/qsort2.html). I'd like to get an explantation for those two rows of casting. I'm not familiar with this "double casting".

```
int myptrstructcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    struct mystruct *sp1 = *(struct mystruct * const *)p1;
    struct mystruct *sp2 = *(struct mystruct * const *)p2;
```

I thought it should be:

```
int myptrstructcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    struct mystruct *sp1 = (struct mystruct *)p1;
    struct mystruct *sp2 = (struct mystruct *)p2;
```

Comment: when `qsort()` calls your comparison function, it can't pass the *value* of the two arrayelements it wants to compare, because they are not of constant size. So it instead passes *pointers*  to the start of the arrayelements it wants to compare.

Comment: In C (in the 2nd) this cast doesn't need! The correct is the second! If you use the first you are saying that you want assign the contents of a structure to a structure! The * outside the parenthesis means you want the contents pointed by p, the cast means the contents is of the type struct mystruct!. In the example you quote the aren't cast and * .

Comment: What is the meaning of `struct mystruct * const *`? Without the `const*` it fails to cast correctly. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you were sorting an array of `int`.  Your comparator would be passed a pair of `int *` disguised as `void *`; one level of indirection is added.

If you are sorting an array of `struct mystruct *`, your comparator is passed `struct mystruct **` disguised as `void *`; one level of indirection is added.

> What is the meaning of `struct mystruct * const *`? Without the `const*` it fails to cast correctly. Why?

Whaddya mean by 'without the `const *` it fails to cast correctly'? Without the `const`, it works OK. Without the second `*`, it doesn't work because the function is passed a `struct mystruct **` (give or take some const-ness) and if you omit the second star, you are abusing the type system.

Consider:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int i;
};

int myptrstructcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
int myptrstructcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    struct mystruct *sp1 = *(struct mystruct **)p1;
    struct mystruct *sp2 = *(struct mystruct **)p2;

    if (sp1->i < sp2->i)
        return -1;
    else if (sp1->i > sp2->i)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine.  It also compiles fine when you add the `const` between the `**`.  Personally, I'd not include the `const` in the casting.  What I would do is const-qualify the `sp1` and `sp2` pointers:

```
    struct mystruct const *sp1 = *(struct mystruct **)p1;
    struct mystruct const *sp2 = *(struct mystruct **)p2;
```

or:

```
    const struct mystruct *sp1 = *(struct mystruct **)p1;
    const struct mystruct *sp2 = *(struct mystruct **)p2;
```

This promises not to modify the objects that they point at in the function, which is actually crucial to the correct performance of `qsort()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your clue — in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/qsort2.html) you reference:

> If, on the other hand, you're sorting pointers to structures, you'll need indirection,

You are sorting a list of pointers to structs.  The pointers have to be juggled in the list by the sort, which means you are passing the pointers in the list by reference (via a pointer to a pointer) for comparison.

Comment: Is there a source you're quoting?  If so, you should include a link to the source (or identify it somehow).

Comment: Agreed.  The source was given by the OP in the sentence:

>The following code is taken from an example you may find here.

Answer (score 2):

From [`man qsort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html):

> [...]  comparison function [..] which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared.

"*the objects being compared*" are the elements of the array passed to `qsort()` and as this array to be sorted holds **pointers** the comparsion function receives pointer to pointer as arguments.

To get the array's elements from the arguments passed to the comparsion function those arguments need to be de-referenced though.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function receives *pointers* to array elements. If your array contains elements of some type `T`, then your comparison function will receive `const void *` pointers that should be interpreted as `const T *` pointers.

In your case `T` is equal to `struct mystruct *` (since your array contains pointers). In that case `const T *` is equivalent to `struct mystruct * const*`, which is exactly what you see in your code.

In order to make your code easier to understand you can actually literally introduce a typedef name `T` into the function and split your conversions/dereferences into separate individual steps

```
int myptrstructcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  typedef mystruct *T;             // array elements are pointers
  const T *pel1 = p1, *pel2 = p2;  // pointers to array elements
  T sp1 = *pe1, sp2 = *pe2;        // values of array elemnts
```

This is equivalent to what you have in the original code;